# How to reframe the columns based on row values?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe as follows:
I want to shrink the data such that column name contains only row values

```
data = {"CHROM":["chr1", "chr1", "chr2", "chr1", "chr7"],
        "Sample":["003C", "001C1", "001C1", "001C", "003C"],
        "001C1.GT" :["C/C", "G/G", "G/A", "C/C", "G/G"],
        "001C1.AD":["2,0", "8,0", "1,2", "1,0", "2,0"],
        "001C1.DP":["2", "8", "3", "1", "2"],
        "001P1.GT":["C/C", "G/G", "G/G", "C/C", "G/G"],
        "001P1.AD":["1,0", "9,0", "3,0", "3,0", "8,0"],
        "001P1.DP":["1", "9", "3", "3", "8"],
        "001P2.GT": ["C/C", "G/G", "G/G", "C/C", "G/G"],
        "001P2.AD":["5,0", "2,0", "3,0", "5,0", "7,0"],
        "001P2.DP":["5", "2", "3", "5", "7"],
        "003C.GT":["C/C", "G/G", "G/G", "C/C", "G/G"], 
        "003C.AD":["2,0", "7,0", "4,0", "13,0", "6,0"],
        "003C.DP":["2", "7", "4", "13", "6"], 
        "003P1.GT":["C/C", "G/G", "G/G", "C/C", "G/G"],
        "003P1.AD":["1,0", "4,0", "2,0", "7,0", "7,0"],
        "003P1.DP":["1", "4", "2", "7", "7"],
        "003P2.GT":["C/C", "G/G", "G/G", "C/C", "G/G"], 
        "003P2.AD":["3,0", "8,0", "10,0", "8,0", "5,0"],
        "003P2.DP":["3", "8", "10", "8", "5"]
       }
dfg = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

dfg

The dataframe looks as follows:

```
CHROM   Sample  001C1.GT    001C1.AD    001C1.DP    001P1.GT    001P1.AD    001P1.DP    001P2.GT    001P2.AD    001P2.DP    003C.GT 003C.AD 003C.DP 003P1.GT    003P1.AD    003P1.DP    003P2.GT    003P2.AD    003P2.DP
0   chr1    003C    C/C         2,0         2           C/C         1,0         1           C/C         5,0         5           C/C     2,0     2       C/C         1,0         1           C/C         3,0         3
1   chr1    001C1   G/G         8,0         8           G/G         9,0         9           G/G         2,0         2           G/G     7,0     7       G/G         4,0         4           G/G         8,0         8
2   chr2    001C1   G/A         1,2         3           G/G         3,0         3           G/G         3,0         3           G/G     4,0     4       G/G         2,0         2           G/G         10,0        10
3   chr1    001C    C/C         1,0         1           C/C         3,0         3           C/C         5,0         5           C/C     13,0    13      C/C         7,0         7           C/C         8,0         8
4   chr7    003C    G/G         2,0         2           G/G         8,0         8           G/G         7,0         7           G/G     6,0     6       G/G         7,0         7           G/G         5,0         5
```

I want to shrink the data such that column name contains only row values
expected output:

```
CHROM   Sample  C.GT    C.AD    C.DP    P1.GT   P1.AD   P1.DP   P2.GT   P2.AD   P2.DP
chr1    003C    C/C     2,0     2       C/C     1,0     1       C/C     3,0     3
chr1    001C1   G/G     8,0     8       G/G     9,0     9       G/G     2,0     2
chr2    001C1   G/A     1,2     3       G/G     3,0     3       G/G     3,0     3
chr1    001C    C/C     1,0     1       C/C     3,0     3       C/C     5,0     5
chr7    003C    G/G     6,0     6       G/G     7,0     7       G/G     5,0     5
```

I want to keep only the values from column that partially matches dfg['Sample'].

in the first case: Sample is `003C` . So I wanted to extract the values from column that matches 003: ie  columns `003C.GT`, `003C.AD`, `003C.DP`, `003P1.GT`,`003P1.AD`, `003P1.DP`, `003P2.GT`,`003P2.AD`,`003P2.DP`

such that first row look like:

```
CHROM   Sample  C.GT    C.AD    C.DP    P1.GT   P1.AD   P1.DP   P2.GT   P2.AD   P2.DP
chr1    003C    C/C     2,0     2       C/C     1,0     1       C/C     3,0     3
```

Similary, I have Sample as 001, 010, 011, 033, 044, 003 etc, about 300 samples

Comment: @sammywemmy - there is less number of columns in ouput.

Comment: @svp, kindly explain a bit more what you are looking for, and also what you have tried

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.melt`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.melt.html), filter by first 3 letters with columns names, for `C` is necessary `replace` and last reshape it by [`DataFrame.pivot`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html):

```
df = df.melt(['CHROM','Sample'])

df = df[df['Sample'].str[:3].eq(df['variable'].str[:3])]
df['variable'] = df['variable'].str[3:].replace('C1','C', regex=True)
df = df.pivot(index=['CHROM','Sample'], columns='variable', values='value').reset_index().rename_axis(None, axis=1)
print (df)
  CHROM Sample C.AD C.DP C.GT P1.AD P1.DP P1.GT P2.AD P2.DP P2.GT
0  chr1   001C  1,0    1  C/C   3,0     3   C/C   5,0     5   C/C
1  chr1  001C1  8,0    8  G/G   9,0     9   G/G   2,0     2   G/G
2  chr1   003C  2,0    2  C/C   1,0     1   C/C   3,0     3   C/C
3  chr2  001C1  1,2    3  G/A   3,0     3   G/G   3,0     3   G/G
4  chr7   003C  6,0    6  G/G   7,0     7   G/G   5,0     5   G/G
```

Answer (score 0):

**Step 1**
You can use

```
df_001 = dfg.filter(regex='001') # filter columns contains the pattern '001'
df_001 = pd.concat([dfg[['CHROM', 'Sample']], df_001], axis=1) # concatenate with columns ['CHROM', 'Sample'] from the original dataframe
df_001
```

to filter columns that contain the pattern '001'

**Step 2**
You can then use pandas **string replace** to remove the character from the column names that follow the regular expression pattern

```
df_001.columns = df_001.columns.str.replace(r'001', '')
```

**Step 3**
Code below gives all the unique values in the column 'Sample'

```
dfg['Sample'].unique()
```

You can repeat step 1 and step 2 for all the unique columns

**Step 4**
At the end, if you want, you can concatenate all the dataframes to form a new dataframe

```
df_full = pd.concat([df_001, df_003, df_001C1])
```

Answer (score 0):

In case you can iterate over the `Sample` column,
You can iterate over the column names and filter out specific specific ones if they start with a value like `003C`. Later, you can filter those specific columns. The following snippet should help

```py
sample = "003C"
cols = [x for x in df.columns if x.startswith(sample)]

df[cols]
```